# array subscript is of type 'char' warning not sure how to clear

Tags: c, subscript

I was hoping to get some help with warning coming up on my code, it does run correctly I cannot seem to clear them.
the errors are:

```
A32.c:42:13: warning: array subscript is of type 'char' [-Wchar-subscripts]
       table[pattern[i]] = m - 1 - i;
            ^~~~~~~~~~~


A32.c:55:18: warning: array subscript is of type 'char' [-Wchar-subscripts]
       i += table[text[i]];
                 ^~~~~~~~
A32.c:74:13: warning: array subscript is of type 'char' [-Wchar-subscripts]
       table[pattern[i]] = m - 1 - i;
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
A32.c:88:22: warning: array subscript is of type 'char' [-Wchar-subscripts]
           i += table[text[i]];
```

The code is:

```
int horspool_search(char* text, char* pattern) {
   int n = strlen(text);
   int m = strlen(pattern);
   int count = 0;
   int shifts = 0;

   // Create a shift table
   int table[256];
   for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
       table[i] = m;
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < m - 1; i++) {
       table[pattern[i]] = m - 1 - i;
   }

   int i = m - 1;
   while (i < n) {
       int j = 0;
       while (j < m && text[i - j] == pattern[m - 1 - j]) {
           j++;
       }
       shifts++;
       if (j == m) {
           count++;
       }
       i += table[text[i]];
   }
   printf("Horspool's algorithm shifts: %d\n", shifts);
   return count;
}

// Function to implement the Boyer-Moore algorithm
int boyer_moore_search(char* text, char* pattern) {
   int n = strlen(text);
   int m = strlen(pattern);
   int count = 0;
   int shifts = 0;

   // Create a shift table
   int table[256];
   for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
       table[i] = m;
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < m - 1; i++) {
       table[pattern[i]] = m - 1 - i;
   }

   int i = m - 1;
   while (i < n) {
       int j = 0;
       while (j < m && text[i - j] == pattern[m - 1 - j]) {
           j++;
       }
       shifts++;
       if (j == m) {
           count++;
           i += m;
       } else {
           i += table[text[i]];
       }
   }
   printf("Boyer-Moore algorithm shifts: %d\n", shifts);
   return count;
}
```

I am not too sure what change needs to be made, assuming it is something small and the same for all 4 warnings

Comment: you are using a 'char' to index an array. this works but might not be what you expect. Hence the warning. cast the char to an int and the complaint will disappear

Comment: I think the concern is that type `char` might be signed, leading to possibly unexpected negative subscripts.  Casting to `(int)` will make the *warning* go away, but not the potential problem!  So I think a better fix would probably be to change or cast `pattern` to `unsigned char *`.

Comment: @SteveSummit A cast to `unsigned char` will be safe though (given that `table` is large enough to hold all possible values).

Comment: Its usually better (and easier) to use an explicit mask rather than a cast to get the char value into the right range: `table[pattern[i] & 0xff]`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this warning is the type `char` may be signed or unsigned depending on the target platform and the compiler configuration.  It is a common portability issue to ignore this and use `char` values to index into tables as if they are never negative.

In your code, you indeed assume that `char` is unsigned and has a range of `0` to `255`.  While the type `char` is almost always 8-bit (except for some obscure DSPs and antique mainframes), many compilers consider it signed with a range of `-128` to `127`.  On such systems, your code would have undefined behavior if any of the `char` values encountered are outside the range `0` to `127`, ie: if the strings contain non-ASCII bytes such as UTF-8 encoded glyphs beyond U+007F.

You can avoid this issue by casting the `char` values as `unsigned char` or by using `unsigned char *` pointers to manipulate arrays of characters that serve as index values.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <limits.h>

size_t horspool_search(const char *text, const char *pattern) {
    size_t n = strlen(text);
    size_t m = strlen(pattern);
    size_t count = 0;
    size_t shifts = 0;

    if (m == 0)
        return 0;

    // Create a shift table
    size_t table[UCHAR_MAX + 1];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < UCHAR_MAX + 1; i++) {
        table[i] = m;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m - 1; i++) {
        table[(unsigned char)pattern[i]] = m - 1 - i;
    }

    size_t i = m - 1;
    while (i < n) {
        size_t j = 0;
        while (j < m && text[i - j] == pattern[m - 1 - j]) {
            j++;
        }
        shifts++;
        if (j == m) {
            count++;
        }
        i += table[(unsigned char)text[i]];
    }
    printf("Horspool's algorithm shifts: %zu\n", shifts);
    return count;
}

// Function to implement the Boyer-Moore algorithm
size_t boyer_moore_search(const char *text, const char *pattern) {
    size_t n = strlen(text);
    size_t m = strlen(pattern);
    size_t count = 0;
    size_t shifts = 0;

    if (m == 0)
        return 0;

    // Create a shift table
    size_t table[UCHAR_MAX + 1];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < UCHAR_MAX + 1; i++) {
        table[i] = m;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m - 1; i++) {
        table[(unsigned char)pattern[i]] = m - 1 - i;
    }

    size_t i = m - 1;
    while (i < n) {
        size_t j = 0;
        while (j < m && text[i - j] == pattern[m - 1 - j]) {
            j++;
        }
        shifts++;
        if (j == m) {
            count++;
            i += m;
        } else {
            i += table[(unsigned char)text[i]];
        }
    }
    printf("Boyer-Moore algorithm shifts: %zu\n", shifts);
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast into a non-`char` (like an `unsigned char`) to get rid of the warning:

```c
i += table[(unsigned char)text[i]];
```

You could also declare the lookup table to be the correct size by using `CHAR_BIT`.

```c
#include <limits.h>

int table[1u << CHAR_BIT]; // 256 on most platforms
for (int i = 0; i < (1u << CHAR_BIT); i++) {
```

`table` will then be the correct size for whatever size a `char` has on your system.